# How to dynamically restrict SSH access to a given user

Tags: ssh, debian, pam

The goal here is to create a script to easily manage reservation for a machine. When a user reserve the machine, it should be the only one able to access the machine for a given time (except admins of course).

I already found a solution with PAM. This single line in `/etc/pam.d/sshd` would have resolve my problem:

```
auth required pam_listfile.so item=user sense=allow file=/etc/ssh/sshd.allow onerr=fail
```

with the user login in `/etc/ssh/sshd.allow`

But it does not work at all:

```
$ cat /etc/ssh/sshd.allow 
foo

$ tail -f /var/log/auth.log
Dec  1 12:12:05 mini sshd[2697]: Accepted publickey for bar from 192.168.0.11 port 58087 ssh2
Dec  1 12:12:05 mini sshd[2697]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session opened for user bar by (uid=0)
```

Here the `/etc/pam.d/sshd` file

```
# PAM configuration for the Secure Shell service
auth       required     pam_env.so # [1]
auth       required     pam_env.so envfile=/etc/default/locale
auth required pam_listfile.so item=user sense=allow file=/etc/ssh/sshd.allow onerr=fail
@include common-auth
account    required     pam_nologin.so
@include common-account
@include common-session
session    optional     pam_motd.so # [1]
session    optional     pam_mail.so standard noenv # [1]
session    required     pam_limits.so
@include common-password
```

I am running a Debian Squeeze box, I don't know if the behaviour of PAM is different with this.

Comment: What does the rest of the stack look like?

Comment: Could you confirm that your sshd is set up to use the PAM service, with `grep PAM /etc/ssh/sshd_config`?

Comment: @MatHatter: I confirm, sshd uses PAM

Comment: @Ignacio: what do you mean with the stack?

Comment: The stack of PAM directives within the same configuration file, `account`,  `auth`, `password`, and `session`.

Comment: @Ignacio: post edited

Answer (score 1):

Similar idea to above: Could you use AllowGroups in sshd.conf to allow a specific group (+ a group for admins), then add and remove users from the group using your authentication system, preventing you from having to edit files at all, or at least only edit files with well established interfaces (/etc/group via usermod etc).

Answer (score 0):

Why  you didnt use   in /etc/ssh/sshd_config in section  AllowUsers  user1  user2 user3

Comment: Because I want to be able to dynamically generate a list of users which are able to connect. With your solution, I should parse and edit sshd_config file in my script... Not safe.

Answer (score 0):

You can very easily use pam_access for this:

```
# /etc/pam.d/system-auth
account     required      pam_access.so
```

Then control who has access as follows:

```
# /etc/security/access.conf
+ : root otheruser : ALL
- : ALL : ALL
```